# How to maintain scroll position of page when it has iframe control on that textbox has focus?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

In my webpage I am using one iframe control and it is in update panel it will refresh after every 4 seconds and the focus is set to one of the textbox in iframe. I want to maintain the scroll position of page but after every 4 seconds the scroll position is going to the focused text box.

I've used `MAintainScrollpositononPostBack` option

and following javascript code

```
function scroll()
      {
      var obj = document.getElementById("Form1"); 
      obj.scrollTop = obj.scrollHeight;
      }
```

Can anyone please explain how to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Do you mean the scroll position of the container page, or the iframe?

Comment: container page (web page)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the code in the below link

http://medikola.blogspot.in/2013/05/script-for-maintaing-scroll-position.html

Comment: tried to use this answer as its **acepted** but instead it is a dead link..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is not to set focus to the text box when it is updated, this means that the scoll position won't be changed at all unless some bit of code you are using is still setting focus to an offscreen element.

If you must set focus on the text box when it is updated, then save the scroll position and restore it.

```
var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
var left = (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);

//update your text box and set focus here

window.scrollTo(left, top);
```